# Stylesheets and Symfony

Tags: php, html, css, symfony

Is there anyone that can explain me how stylesheets work in Symfony?

According to the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#including-css-stylesheets), I should use the following code:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {% stylesheets 'bundles/app/css/*' filter='cssrewrite' %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
    {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}
```

So this is how my base.html.twig `<head>` tag would look like:

```
3 <head>
4     <meta charset="UTF-8" />
5     <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
6     {% block stylesheets %}
7         {% stylesheets 'bundles/app/css' filter='cssrewrite' %}
8             <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="" />
9         {% endstylesheets %}
10     {% endblock %}
11     <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}" />
12 </head>
```

But when I go to any page, I see the following error:

`Unexpected "stylesheets" tag (expecting closing tag for the "block" tag defined near line 7) in base.html.twig at line 7.`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need manually install and configure assetic - as it's no longer added by default to Symfony (https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/pull/860).

You have all the informations in liked by you cookbook.

Comment: Can I ask, how does `{{ asset_url }}` work? 
For example I'm using this code: `{% block stylesheets %}{% sylesheets 'bundles/app/css' filter='cssrewrite'             '@AppBundle/Resources/public/css/main.css' %}<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset_url }}" />{% endstylesheets %}{% endblock %}` but it does not load in my stylesheet?

Comment: asset_url prints final url for you connected and processed by set filters assets.

Comment: How come it prints `href="/css/3e7b5a2_part_1_main_1.css"` instead of `href="/css/main.css"` or something instead?